# Simulate Mouse Hover over Any UI element for any windows application

Tags: c++, windows, mouseevent, inputsimulator

For context, my mission is to simulate all mouse interactions/inputs for a specific window handle without having the mouse actually be over said window.

I’ve gotten very far with `SendMessageA()` and sending over `WM_LBUTTONDOWN/UP`, and the `R` version of that for right click.

For example `SendMessageA(m_TargetWindow, WM_RBUTTONUP, MK_RBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(x,y));` works great for sending a Right Button Up at location `x,y` of the window.

That said, first and foremost, if my mission is not possible for all mouse interactions, including simulating drag, and in this case hover (and it's end), then that would save me a lot of time.

If it is possible, then I'll continue to figure out the rest, but right now hover is being more tricky than the other send messages commands (Scroll is/was too, but I worked around it for now). Reading the docs does indicate some nuances, like [`TrackMouseEvent()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-trackmouseevent), but I haven't made sense of it yet. I'm also not sure if Hover is the right way to think about it, as it might be a Mouse Enter/Leave type of deal.

This is what I've tried so far.

```
SendMessageA(m_TargetWindow, WM_MOUSEHOVER, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(x,y));
```

and

```
TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme;
tme.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
tme.dwFlags = TME_HOVER;
tme.hwndTrack = m_TargetWindow;
tme.dwHoverTime = HOVER_DEFAULT;

SendMessageA(m_TargetWindow, WM_MOUSEHOVER, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(x,y));
```

The idea being that at location `x,y` of the window, it would simulate a hover event for the `m_TargetWindow`.

Comment: See `SendInput` _"...Synthesizes keystrokes, mouse motions, and button clicks...."_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput

Comment: @RichardCritten I started off using that but SendInput seems to use the actual actual virtual mouse cursor which is not what I want. I need the virtual mouse to be on a certain monitor doing other potential things while still simulating mouse inputs on another specific window. If I'm confused and SendInput doesn't always need to use the actual virtual mouse cursor to simulate interactions then I would like to know how.

Comment: I've also sort of gotten one step closer to solving a particulate windows event that handles this. I thought it would be hover, but a lot of windows seem to use WM_MOUSEMOVE event to make the "Hover" work. That said it isn't fool proof, it seems to work in some cases and in others partially and in others hardly. Not sure what events most windows use to simulate a highlight effect on a button for example.

Comment: I’m wondering if injecting touch input would be more useful?