# Simulate mouse hover in windows application using win32 api

Tags: winapi, mouse, mousehover

With a game application (may have been **minimized or hidden**), I have a button that only shows up when I hover over it. I need to write an script (by c# or python) that can click that button without moving my cursor. I was able to simulate click event with `SendMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, ...)`, but i don't know how to make that button show up.

I have seen a tool that can do it, I don't know how they do it.

My problem seems similar to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68142696/simulate-mouse-hover-over-any-ui-element-for-any-windows-application?newreg=83fbc15296e547e69fb73e53114f3d2a).

I won't need `SendInput` or `mouse_event` because **it will move my cursor**.

Any one can help? Is there another unrelated way?

Comment: I left a comment on the same question you asked recently (and deleted, apparently). The short of it is: You can't. The answer doesn't change just because you keep asking.

Comment: @IInspectable I used a tool that can do that, what I needed was a way to solve the problem. The solution I've come up with is just a direction.